# Avoid same ints of random numbers in array :(

Tags: c++, c, loops

im doing some excercises to practice the few things i've learned this months and no matter what i can't solve this. I have to fill an array with random numbers, thats good, but now i have to CHECK that those numbers chosen randomly are not repeated, so like an array that says "10,2,5,10,4" is **WRONG** and the second 10 should be changed by ***another random number*** until it doesnt match with any other number on the array.

Im tryin to understand why THIS way is wrong, i know yt videos show a different way but i want to recognize if there's a logic problem with my solution or if im just coding it poorly.

I tried THIS because that's what came to mind but.. it doesnt work lol, here's the code:

```
  using namespace std;

void randomArray(int []);
void mostrarArray(int[]);
int main()
{
    int i = 0, arrayA[10],arrayB[10];
    srand(time(NULL));
    randomArray(arrayA);
    randomArray(arrayB);
    mostrarArray(arrayA);
    mostrarArray(arrayB);
    return 0;
}
void randomArray(int array[] ) {
    int i = 0, j=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 12;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[i]) {
                array[i] = rand() % 12;
            }
        }
    }
}

void mostrarArray(int array[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: When you detect a duplicate, you're setting it to a new random number, but you forgot to check if the *new* number is a duplicate.  You have to keep checking until the new number differs from all other previous numbers in the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to trace through the logic of the code.